# Mount NodeMCU with Micropython filesystem?

Tags: nodemcu, micropython

I've recently bought a NodeMCU board and flashed Micropython in it. 
I've read about the `boot.py` and `main.py` scripts, but I can't understand how to access them. 
 I have succesfully connected to the Python REPL with the `screen` command and everything works fine.
Is there a way to mount it as an external drive on Mac OS X? Because I haven't found a way till now.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can enable the webrepl and upload via that

I've found this one package very helpful to upload vi the serial.

```
pip install mpfshell

python -m mp.mpfshell
> open COM3 
> put main.py
```

micropython is cool...

Comment: Nice. Meanwhile I've found `ampy` which allows you to do the same. I was wanderind if there was a way to open it as a "normal" device, as I've read that mac os should do that :(

Comment: Yep! I needed only the module, but the whole board costed me a couple of euros more, so that was worth indeed lol

Comment: I don't think there's a driver to mount it on a pc ( PyBoard has one)

Comment: well, I don't think so either but I remember to have read "Mac OS X should see is like a normal mounted device", even though I can't find the page where I read it. I'll leave this question open, hoping I was right lol

Answer (score 1):

Due to some questions I had about the NodeMcu and running Python on it, I just set up a pretty end-to-end documentation [python2nodemcu](https://github.com/pixelstuermer/python2nodemcu) on GitHub.

Viewing, downloading, uploading or listing files of the MicroPython filesystem has its [own section](https://github.com/pixelstuermer/python2nodemcu#uploading-scripts-to-the-device) there.

It utilizes [Ampy](https://github.com/scientifichackers/ampy), a Python library to connect to the MicroPython-based board via its serial connection. For listing all files for example, simply run `python3 ampy/cli.py --port /dev/tty.{device-file} --baud 115200 ls`.

Answer (score 1):

The [mpy-utils](https://github.com/nickzoic/mpy-utils) software package contains a tool called `mpy-fuse` that allows you to mount a MicroPython device from Linux or MacOS using FUSE. I found this tool through [this video](https://youtu.be/NdXtvtYrOs4?t=36) that describes how to set it up and shows how it looks like in action.